# Unable to upload file to /home directory of LINUX using POSTMAN

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I am working on a mobile application that uploads a file to my Linux server. The API is made on Laravel which is within the same Linux Server inside `/var/www/html` directory.

I want my image that is being uploaded from the mobile application to be stored inside `/home/uploads` folder for that I have set `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public` and `FILESYSTEM_PATH=/home/uploads` inside my Laravel Project.

Now I made a function inside my controller to upload my file which is below

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        Storage::putFileAs('Documents/', $request->file, 'Some name.jpg');
    }
}
```

When I try to run the above code directly from my Laravel project, the file gets uploaded inside `/home/uploads/Documents/Some name.jpg` but when I hit the same function using Postman, I get a success message but I see no file inside my folder. What can be the cause of this issue?

Below is a screenshot of how I am sending the file through API using POSTMAN
[image]

Helps appreciated

Comment: are you sending the file correctly? does it enter the if statement with the condition `$request->hasFile('file')` when you use postman ?

Comment: What's the code problem here? That the file is put to the wrong folder, or that you cannot properly trigger the upload using Postman?

Comment: Confirm your $request->file does have file content. Did you add enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: how do I add enctype while making a request from POSTMAN? @Charlie

Comment: It is showing 1 for ```$request->hasFile('file')``` so yeh it is reading the file @N69S

Comment: File is not being uploaded when I send a file through POSTMAN @NicoHaase

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If the problem is sending the file properly through Postman, why does your title talk about storing the file in the proper directory?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is your issue, there is no details about how you send request. You should add more details into your question, how did you send request from postman, are you sending request as form data or as ajax?

Comment: I have added a screenshot and updated my title

Comment: Once more: is the root problem uploading a file using Postman, or putting the uploaded file into the proper directory? Please clarify that. Did you try to dump the request to inspect it?

Comment: The file is properly uploaded when done through the laravel application. When I try to run the same thing through POSTMAN, it doesn't work. So the problem is uploading file through POSTMAN and yes when I try to dump or debug, my function is running perfectly, I am getting the file, I can check its size and do all the stuff but as soon as I hit the ```Storage::putFileAs()``` function, it is not working

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If everything works when you dump the details, but not if you remove the dumping methods, share **how** you dump

Comment: Did you add csrf token into your postman request? You are sending as form data, might be the issue.

Comment: If it was due to CSRF, then it should have shown me 419

Answer (score -2):

maybe it is not a Laravel problem but a linux system wrong configuration try to set the www folder permissions recursively :

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www
```

indeed if laravel does not return an error it is possible that the problem is at a lower level

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does this resolve any of the two problems (sending the request properly in Postman, putting the file **outside** of `/var/www`)

Comment: `chmd 777` is ALWAYS a bad idea, especially with `-R`.

Comment: 755 so at some point you will have to write